# When a ceiling fan is turned on I get 440v in the room circuit

Tags: ceiling-fan, voltage

I installed a new [ceiling fan](https://www.orientelectric.com/fan/ceiling-fans/aero-series/aeroslim). When switched it on, I get 440v in the entire room circuit; I had stabiliser that showed the voltage. I was surprised. I took a multimeter and measured the voltage it too showed 440v. If I switch off the fan switch then the voltage comes down to 220v.

I removed the fan and connected a bulb over there and the voltage is not varying (it's at 220v as expected). Checked the Hot and Neutral line they seems to be fine as well.

Any idea on what could be going wrong here? How the fan can trigger this kind of voltage variation?
1 & 2 Are fan images & 3 is the switch.

Comment: I’d really like to see a photo of your panel.  I’ve never seen a home with 480 service.

Comment: Where are you at (which country)?  is your fan on some kind of speed controller? photos of the wiring where the fan connects and where the controls for the fan are would help.

Comment: It seems your photos didn't post...and yes, where on this planet are you?

Comment: And make sure you turn the power off at the circuit breaker before someone hurts himself or burns the house down!

Comment: Were your measurements *exactly* 220V and 440V, or were you rounding them off to common values?  Also, is this a residential or commercial building?  And I agree with the other comments that we're gonna need to know a country and likely get a picture of your breaker panel to help solve this.

Comment: Their other post says they live in India, which is also a question about electrical issues.

Comment: Yeah I'm in India, is it not right to post questions over here? The fan isn't connected to regulator to control the speed since the fan came with a in-built regulator. The place where I live has few houses and it's difficult to get qualified electrician and also to get support from electricity supply company. I'm also not a electrical engineer but I do have fair amount of knowledge. Hence trying to gain knowledge by asking questions here and understand how things actually work in real life

Comment: I found the issue and fixed looks like the forum isn't for supporting in different countries and general questions.